# (Astrophysics) How to calculate photons detected by a radiometer over a period of 10 seconds?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

I know the Flux (calculated from flux density), and frequency but i dont think I have area.

This is the question, it is part d and ive done all other parts:

"Consider three widely separated frequencies:

i) 5.5×1014 Hz

ii) 4.8×1017 Hz

iii) 5.0×107 Hz

1a. Convert frequency to wavelength for each of these frequencies, and state which part of the electromagnetic the frequencies are situated in. [1 mark]

1b. Calculate the energy of a single photon at each of these frequencies. Express your answer in
electron-volts (eV) [1 mark].

1c. Consider an astronomical source with a flux density on Earth of fν = 250 milliJansky (mJy), which is constant across all frequencies. We observe it with a radiometer (a light-measuring instrument) that has a uniform response across all frequencies. It operates by integrating the flux density over a range of frequencies that is 4 Gigahertz (GHz) wide, centered on a given frequency of interest. What is the flux picked up by the radiometer (in units of W m−2) within a band centered on each of the three frequencies?[2 marks]

1d. At each frequency, how many photons would be picked up by the radiometer, per unit area, in
an exposure time of 10 seconds? What can you conclude about these frequency regimes in which the
quantum nature of radiation could be important when doing astronomical observations? [2 marks]"

I have seen somewhere the equation Number of photons = (F * A * t) / E
Where, F is the flux picked up by the detector
A is the effective area of the detector (in square meters),
t is the exposure time (in seconds), and
E is the energy of a single photon (in joules).
Is this equation correct? Can I use it even though I dont have A? Is there a different equation I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use it even though I dont have A?

You don't need to have the area, because the question asks you for "how many photons would be picked up by the radiometer, **per unit area**," [emphasis added].

You are explicitly asked for the photon count per unit area, not the total photon arrival rate over a specified area.

Edit to add:

Since this doesn't seem to be enough, I'll work through one of the cases. Let's do $5.5\times 10^{14}\ {\rm Hz}$.

I'll skip part 1a, since that result isn't needed to do the rest of the calculations.

> 1b. Calculate the energy of a single photon at each of these frequencies. Express your answer in electron-volts (eV)

$$ E = \frac{hc}{\nu}$$
$$ E = \frac{(1.055\times 10^{-34}\ {\rm eV\cdot s}) 
             (2.998\times 10^8\ {rm m\cdot s^{-1}})}
            {5.5\times 10^{14}\ \rm s^{-1}}$$
Keeping in mind the sig figs provided in the input data:
$$ E = 5.8\times10^{-41}\ {\rm J}$$
I'll leave it to you to convert this to eV, since we'll just use the value in joules for the later steps.

> 1c. Consider an astronomical source with a flux density on Earth of fν = 250 milliJansky (mJy), which is constant across all frequencies. ...

$$1\ {\rm Jy} = 10^{-26}\ {\rm W\cdot m^{-2} \cdot Hz^{-1}}$$
Therefore
$$1\ {\rm mJy} = 10^{-29}\ {\rm W\cdot m^{-2} \cdot Hz^{-1}}$$

> ... We observe it with a radiometer (a light-measuring instrument) that has a uniform response across all frequencies. It operates by integrating the flux density over a range of frequencies that is 4 Gigahertz (GHz) wide, centered on a given frequency of interest. What is the flux picked up by the radiometer (in units of W m−2) within a band centered on each of the three frequencies?

I don't even know this topic area, but I know I have to multiply here from dimensional analysis:
$$ \Phi = f_\nu \Delta \nu$$
$$ \Phi = (250\ {\rm mJy}) (4\ {\rm GHz})$$
$$ \Phi = (250\times 10^{-29}\ {\rm W\cdot m^{-2} \cdot Hz^{-1}} ) 
          (4\times 10^9\ {\rm Hz})$$
$$ \Phi = 1 \times 10^{-17}{\rm W\cdot m^{-2}}$$
This is the energy flux received by the detector.

> 1d. At each frequency, how many photons would be picked up by the radiometer, per unit area, in an exposure time of 10 seconds?

This is back to regular radiometry, which I do know something about, but you should still be able to work out what to do from dimensional analysis.

We divide the power flux by the photon energy to get the photon flux, and multiply by the observation time to get the total photon count density in that time window:
$$ N = \frac{\Phi\ \Delta t}{E}$$
$$ N = \frac{(1 \times 10^{-17}{\rm W\cdot m^{-2}})(10\ {\rm s})}
            {5.8\times10^{-41}\ {\rm J}}$$
$$ N = 1.7\times 10^{24}\ {\rm m^{-2}}$$

To get the actual photon count, you'd multiply this value by the actual detector area, but you weren't asked for that, so you don't need the detector area.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks a lot for your reply. What do I need to do to calculate the photon count per unit area?

Comment: @jedijessop, if you already solved 1b and 1c you shouldn't have any problem with that. The biggest challenges in this problem are converting all the given values to consistent units (for example, convert everything to SI), and doing dimensional analysis to figure out how to get the requested answers from the givens.

Comment: Hmmm, I've been stuck on this problem for a couple days and am still not sure. Any help would be appreciated. I was thinking dividing the total Energy of these given frequencies by the energy of one photon to get the photon number, but i dont have the total enegy of the frequencies and im not sure over what time period that calculation would give me. Probably per second based on units but im not sure. Is there an equation you are thinking of? I'm using this for revision and can't find a solution so if you could help that would be very helpful :). Thanks

Comment: any ideas on how to solve it? thanks

Comment: @jedijessop, Did you see my edits? I completely solved one of the frequencies you were asked about. To do the other ones, just do the same steps with different numbers.

Comment: thanks so much! huge help. yeah sorry i didn't know that you could edit my answer. thanks a lot for helping me out. it's so cool that you do somewhat similar things to do your R&D development in fibre optics and it has an affect on real life. thanks again for your help, I hope you have a great day and enjoy your work.